# Organic Shape with CSS For Image Hover Effect

Tags: html, css

I have a task on organic shape image I want the background color on hover like that particular organic shape image. I am not getting the hover effect on the image with the background colour. i have tried a lot but it's not coming where am i doing wrong. Can anybody point in the right direction to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance...

```css
.at-organic-shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.at-organic-shape figure img:hover {
  background-color: #6495ED;
  border-radius: 35% 80% 65% 70%/50% 65% 70% 85%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-organic-shape">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nHDcuq/1-F19-F06-C-0-F3-E-4055-B0-E5-1-D73728-A7730.png" class="img1"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a pseudo element and a `mix-blend-mode` to hide the color overflow:

```css
.at-organic-shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.at-organic-shape figure {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
}
.at-organic-shape figure:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:transparent;
  mix-blend-mode: color;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.at-organic-shape figure:hover::after {
  background:#6495ED;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-organic-shape">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nHDcuq/1-F19-F06-C-0-F3-E-4055-B0-E5-1-D73728-A7730.png" class="img1"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar effects can be achieved without using a pseudo-element - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/910768/265406

Comment: @UModeL true, but I wanted to keep the overlay idea by using an extra element

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can try with this

`.at-organic-shape figure img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #6495ED) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 #6495ED);
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #6495ED) drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0 #6495ED);
    border-radius: 35% 80% 65% 70%/50% 65% 70% 85%;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}`

. This will give you outline of black around your image. If you want different color you can just change. Is that you wanted?

Comment: I want the colour on the image when I hover on that

Comment: how you mean on the image? You mean around the image or to make it completely solid color so that image is not visible?

Comment: background overlay on the image when hover on the image

Comment: Do you need that shape of image thought? It can easily be done with square image

Comment: I want the background colour on the image whenever I hover on image

Comment: Yes I get it but if you have squared image for example you can do it easily check here http://jsfiddle.net/Lc237kmd/